# How to Restore Hard Disk File Icon? Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

One day when I opened My Computer I saw a strange icon for drive D: instead of the usual icon.

How can I restore the original icon? Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of drive icon]

Comment: If you type in `D:\autorun.inf` into Start->Run, does anything come up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Launch a Command Prompt with administrator privileges, and navigate to the root of drive `D:`
2. Run the following:

   ```
   attrib -r -h -s autorun.inf
   del autorun.inf
   ```

This will most likely solve your problem.

Comment: how to run CMD with admin privileges?

Comment: @imdadhusen seems there was a formatting problem in the answer. It should be *.* not .

Comment: yep its attrib<space>-s<space>-h<space>*.*<space>/S<space>/D

Comment: @imdadhusen
Open start, search for command prompt, right click the result and click run as administrator.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution that worked for me. (Windows 8.1)
Open registry editor and navigate to

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \Applications \explorer.exe \ Drives\
```

First backup and then delete all Key with names of Drive for which the icons you need to restore. For example to restore drive icon of C: drive, delete Key "C". Once you are done restart your computer. In my case the culprit was hard disk sentinel which had left overs even after uninstall.

Comment: Interestingly, I have these values left by HDS, however, the drives in my computer are not missing the icon even though the file for the icon is missing. Either they modified another location as well or windows has cached the icon somewhere.

Comment: Your answer is correct for my question, although my question got closed as a duplicate of this one.

http://superuser.com/questions/1141225/program-modified-hard-disk-icons-in-my-computer-in-windows-7?noredirect=1#comment1638762_1141225

Comment: Ha!  It was HardDisk Sentinel that broke mine, too!  I went a-looking for an answer and found your solution here..  but it was *after* that that I read where you said it was HDS.  HDS changed the drive icons for all drives, even though I had uninstalled it - it didn't clean up after itself.

Answer (score 2):

"right click -> properties" on D drive,
Under the "Customize" tab there is a area named "Folder pictures"
choose "Restore Default"

Comment: I have tried but still didn't get result!

Comment: This doesn't always work.  If the icons are set via a registry entry, that registry setting will take precedence, I think.

Answer (score 2):

If the drive is external:
After following the solution with Command Prompt above, reconnect the drive to make the icon restore.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click > Properties > In the name Field, type any name and apply and then tap ok

Comment: Well it might not be a general solution to the problem but atleast it works. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

1. right click on the start menu
2. open disk management
3. right click on the disk
4. select change drive letter and paths
5. click on new
6. finally assign new drive letter

problem solved.