# My whole local disk icons are missing

Tags: windows-7

I'm a Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit) user. And also I use Bitdefender anti-virus program, but that anti-virus program occurs so many crashes on my computer. Today, about an hour ago, it occurs another crash again - a blue screen. And the problem is that the booting speed has been slower, and local disk icons in "my computer" are all missing.

I tried to find the solution, and I tried deleting Autorun.ini(Check this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/307979/how-to-restore-hard-disk-file-icon-windows-7)) but didn't work. I'm experiencing a same problem as in the link.
I need help.

Answer (score 1):

Open an administrative command prompt (Start > type 'cmd' > right-click > run as administrator) and run sfc /scannow. This will validate and repair all Windows system files. Be advised - this could take some time.