# Program Modified Hard Disk Icons in My Computer in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, icons

[image]

Well I installed hard disk sentinel and it changed my drive icons to this. (Didn't like it enough when it would keep adding itself as a startup program whenever I opened it, but my regular SMART reader, thought it was malfunctioning, needed to see if a different reader would read more.)

- Uninstalling the program didn't restore original icons. Re-installing, then running the uninstaller as admin and killing explorer.exe before starting the process did not help either.
- Right clicking the drive into properties and doing restore default icon does not do anything either.
- In "Save-As" dialogue boxes, the drives show up with no icon.

**Anyone know how programs change the default icon for things in My Computer?**

Comment: Check the value for default icon in the registry key:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\explorer.exe\Drives\<DRIVE LETTER>\DefaultIcon

Comment: Found a second registry key with the same deal.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\explorer.exe\Drives\<DRIVE LETTER>\DefaultIcon

Comment: Correct answer:

http://superuser.com/a/1135175/596755

Tested on windows 7.